# assign value to member of struct pointer, within multiple struct pointers and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct, assign

long title. but it is the exact problem i am having.
it may be a misunderstanding of how the struct pointer works, or a problem using tthe correct format. i have the following typedefs of structs combined in a big 'box' for easy passing around the configuration.

```
typedef struct NTC_network{
     unsigned char NET_ID;      
     unsigned char DEV_ADDR;        
}NTC_network;

typedef struct NTC_io_trx_link{
  enum NTC_IO_LINK own_io;
  unsigned char ADDR;
  enum NTC_IO_LINK trx_io;
}NTC_io_trx_link;

//struct to hold status of I/O. 0==OFF 1==ON
typedef struct NTC_config_stpio{
    unsigned char L1:1;
    unsigned char L2:1;
    unsigned char L3:1;
    unsigned char L4:1;
    unsigned char E1:1;
    unsigned char E2:1;
    unsigned char T1:1;
    unsigned char T2:1;
}NTC_config_stpio;

typedef struct NTC_header {
    unsigned char NET_ID;   
    unsigned char DST;      //destination address
    unsigned char SRC;      //source address
    unsigned char PCKT;             
}NTC_header;

typedef struct NTC_default_setup{
    unsigned char DEFAULT_SETUP:1;
}NTC_default_setup;    

typedef struct NTC_data{    
    unsigned char E1;       //resistor value to emulate on E1
    unsigned char E2;       //resistor value to emulate on E2
    unsigned char T1;       //resistor value of temperature sensor on T1
    unsigned char T2;       //resistor value of temperature sensor on T2
    unsigned char D1;       //230VAC detection circuit on/off
    unsigned char D2;       //230VAC detection circuit on/off       
    unsigned char ALRM;     //alarm on off 0xFF=alarm on, 0x00=alarm off            
}NTC_data;

typedef struct NTC_ack{
    unsigned char ACK;      //ACK field 0x00=no ack 0xFF= ack
}NTC_ack;

typedef struct NTC_config {
    NTC_default_setup *DEFAULT_STP;
    NTC_config_stpio *STPIO;
    NTC_config_network *NETWORK;
    NTC_io_trx_link *NTC_link_io;               
}NTC_config;

//struct for payload to send via LoRa
typedef struct NTC_payload{
    NTC_header *Header;
    enum NTC_dc DC; 
    NTC_config *Config;
    NTC_data *Data;
    NTC_ack *Ack;   
}NTC_payload;

typedef struct NTC_runtime_data{
    NTC_payload *pPayload;  
}NTC_runtime_data;
```

and allocating the whole thing at runtime as such:

```
NTC_runtime_data* init_struct_runtime_data(void){   

    NTC_runtime_data *DATA = calloc(1, sizeof(NTC_runtime_data));   

    DATA->pPayload = calloc(2, sizeof(NTC_payload));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++){
        DATA->pPayload[i].Header = calloc(1, sizeof(NTC_header));
        DATA->pPayload[i].DC = NONE; 
        DATA->pPayload[i].Config = calloc(1, sizeof(NTC_config));
        DATA->pPayload[i].Config->DEFAULT_STP = calloc(1, sizeof(NTC_default_setup));
        DATA->pPayload[i].Config->STPIO = calloc(1, sizeof(NTC_config_stpio));      
        DATA->pPayload[i].Config->NETWORK = calloc(1, sizeof(NTC_config_network));
        DATA->pPayload[i].Config->NETWORK->NTC_NETWORK = calloc(1, sizeof(NTC_network));
        DATA->pPayload[i].Config->NTC_link_io = calloc(11, sizeof(NTC_io_trx_link));
        for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
            DATA->pPayload[i].Config->NTC_link_io[j].own_io = j + 1;
        }           
        DATA->pPayload[i].Data = calloc(1, sizeof(NTC_data));
        DATA->pPayload[i].Ack = calloc(1, sizeof(NTC_ack));
    }
    return DATA;
}
```

i am allocating 2 pPayload. one for TX data and one for RX.
all this works fine and there is no problem what so ever assigning values like so:

```
    NTC_runtime_data *pDATA;
    pDATA = init_struct_runtime_data();
```

and then where ever i might pass this struct i can assign as follows:

```
pData->pPayload[0].Header->NET_ID = 0x20;
```

but i am having problems with trying to assign from a struct containing an array as a buffer which looks like this:

```
typedef struct TRX_buffer{
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
    unsigned char *array;
}TRX_buffer;
```

and initializing and reallocating as so:

```
TRX_buffer* init_struct_trx_buffer(void){
    TRX_buffer *trx_buffer = malloc(sizeof(TRX_buffer));
    trx_buffer->array = malloc(4 * sizeof(unsigned char));
    trx_buffer->size = 4;
    trx_buffer->used = 0;
    return trx_buffer;
}
//inserts a byte of data in the buffer and dynamically allocates the buffer
void insert_array(TRX_buffer *trxbuffer, unsigned char data){
    if(trxbuffer->used == trxbuffer->size){
        trxbuffer->size *= 2;
        trxbuffer[0].array = realloc(trxbuffer[0].array, trxbuffer->size * sizeof(unsigned char));
    }
    trxbuffer[0].array[trxbuffer->used] = data;
    trxbuffer->used++;
}
```

so the problem is, some where in my program ,in a function, where i am creating a new instance of the buffer and load data from the radio, which i can see when debugging, i want to load it to my struct and i do it like this

```
NTC_payload* get_payload(NTC_payload *pPayload){    
    TRX_buffer *rx_buffer;
    rx_buffer = init_struct_trx_buffer();

    r_FIFO(rx_buffer);

    pDATA->pPayload[1].Header->NET_ID = trx_buffer->array[0];
```

the correct data is in the `trx_buffer` after my `r_FIFO()` function. but this isn't working. i have tried different methods. but cant get it to take the value from my buffer and assign it to my struct.

what is wrong??

Comment: Step through the program with a debugger and stop at `get_payload`.  After `r_FIFO` is called, check that `trx_buffer->array[0]` is what you expect.  Then do the assignment and check that `pDATA->pPayload[1].Header->NET_ID` is what you expect.  Narrow down from there.

Comment: Already did that. The buffer is filled with what I expect. But the value is not getting put in to the struct

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from init_struct_runtime_data(), so pDATA = init_struct_runtime_data(); gets whatever happened to be in the return register.

Any decent compiler should flag this, if yours doesn't do yourself a favour and uninstall it.

ps: there is a faq around here somewhere that talks about posting complete programs so people can try them with their tools.   It is a good idea, because simply reducing the problem to a publishable version reveals the problem.

Comment: Hello. I see. But it is a copy paste mistake. As I am indeed returning `DATA` in my code. I edited as well

Comment: ok, but what you posted isn’t a problem.   It is a bunch of code fragments, 123 lines of them that generate 12 errors and 62 warnings on my compiler.  How do you expect anybody to help you?  There are some brilliant people monitoring these (modern newsgroup buzzword), I am not one of them.   The other day, somebody asked about a problem he had with the classic aes implementation, and the author of it responded.   Please, go look at the FAQ for how to ask questions and follow it.